# How to submit a CSR to Windows CA for signing from C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, ca, hsm, .net-4.7.2

My scenario:

I have an EC2 instance running **Windows Server 2016 DataCenter OS** in it. This EC2 instance is configured to work as **CA** and **IIS** server (I am testing **cloudhsm** so it is okay for me to have multiple services in the same server). My CA is configured with **RSA#Cavium Key Storage Provider** (as it supports AWS CloudHSM Key Storage Provider). Now from my sample .Net WebAPI app, I can create a CSR using below code:

```
private async Task<CertificateSigningResponse> ActualSigningAsync(CertificateSigningRequest csr)
        {
            CertificateSigningResponse certificateSigningResponse;
            try
            {
                using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(csr.KeySize))
                {
                    CertificateRequest request = new CertificateRequest("CN=servername-CA2", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                    OidCollection oidCollection = new OidCollection();
                    oidCollection.Add(new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8"));

                    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(true, false, 0, true));
                    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(oidCollection, true));
                    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(request.PublicKey, false));

                    var serialNumberInBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                    /*
                    // below line creates a self signed certificate
                    var selfSignedCertificate = request.Create(
                        new X500DistinguishedName("CN=servername-CA2"),
                        X509SignatureGenerator.CreateForRSA(rsa, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1),
                        DateTimeOffset.Now,
                        DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1),
                        serialNumberInBytes);
                    */

                    var certSigningRequest = request.CreateSigningRequest(X509SignatureGenerator.CreateForRSA(rsa, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1));

                    if (certSigningRequest != null)
                    {
                        certificateSigningResponse = PopulateCertificateSigningResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(certSigningRequest), $"Sample Cert with Sl#: {certSigningRequest}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        certificateSigningResponse = PopulateCertificateSigningResponse("", $"Error: {request.PublicKey}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                certificateSigningResponse = PopulateCertificateSigningResponse(string.Empty, ex.Message);
            }

            return certificateSigningResponse;

        }
```

Now, I want to send this CSR to my CA (which is running on EC2) and get it signed. Once signed, I want to send the signed certificate back to the user. Currently, I have hosted my sample webapi app on the same EC2 instance. This app actually exposes an endpoint, which I can hit via postman and pass in some data as request body (POST).

So, ideally, the app receives my POST request and extracts data from it, then using that data, it is creating a csr. And now I want to send this csr to my CA, get it signed and finally return the signed certificate to user. Below pseudo code may give you some idea about my requirements:

```
//pseudo code; not existed
// request is generated in above code
var caService = new CAService();//can use my ca info i.e. name, public dns, ip
var response = await caService.SignAsync(request);//response should be a cert
return response;
```

I have seen few posts using **CertUtilLib/CertEnrollLib** but I want to achieve this by fully managed code. Also if it is not possible, please suggest me some alternatives.  Thanks.

**EDIT 1 (after Michal's comment)**

Below are some info for your interest:

**Current Scenario:**

- we are using a 3rd party API to sign some critical data.
- In this way, we make a POST request to that particular endpoint with the data we wanted to be signed.
- The 3rd party API handles everything for us behind the scene. We know that they are using some HSM service at their end to sign data.

**My intention:**

- I am trying to achieve the same functionality using AWS CloudHSM.
- The calling process should be same, i.e. we should still call an endpoint with data and get the signed copy of the data.
- For this, my understanding was to create the CSR at server end and sign it using CloudHSM from within the server.
- For that, I have created a sample .Net API app that exposes an endpoint where I can post my data to be signed.
- Then it is my app's responsibility to create the CSR (*I did it already*), and then send the CSR to a CA (this is my EC2 Windows
  Server 2016 instance which has the CA feature enabled on it) for
  signing (I am stuck here at the moment).

Comment: I'm not fully sure that I understand what you are trying to achieve, but CSR requires to be signed with private key. If you are applying modifications or building the CSR elsewhere than you store private key, it will be quite problematic (at least this was my experience with Windows CA - I remember there is an interface in EJBCA that can handle such requests). You have several options how to connect to Windows CA - there is a web interface, a soap webservice and SCEP options you can use. It would be easier to advise if you explained why you build CSR on a server rather than directly on client

Comment: @MichalGluchowski Sorry for the delayed response. Please see the EDIT 1 section for more details. Thanks